# Which ports should I open in firewall on nodes with Apach Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

When I try to run my flow on Apache Flink standalone cluster I see the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Update task on instance aaa0859f6af25decf1f5fc1821ffa55d @ app-2 - 4 slots - URL: akka.tcp://flink@192.168.38.98:46369/user/taskmanager failed due to:
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution$6.onFailure(Execution.java:954)
    at akka.dispatch.OnFailure.internal(Future.scala:228)
    at akka.dispatch.OnFailure.internal(Future.scala:227)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:174)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.applyOrElse(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:28)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$onFailure$1.apply(Future.scala:136)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$onFailure$1.apply(Future.scala:134)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka.tcp://flink@192.168.38.98:46369/user/taskmanager#1804590378]] after [10000 ms]
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:333)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$7.run(Scheduler.scala:117)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:599)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:597)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(Scheduler.scala:467)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$8.executeBucket$1(Scheduler.scala:419)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$8.nextTick(Scheduler.scala:423)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$8.run(Scheduler.scala:375)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Seems like port 46369 blocked by firewall. It is true because I read [configuration section](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/setup/config.html) and open these ports only:

```
6121:
  comment: Apache Flink TaskManager (Data Exchange)
6122:
  comment: Apache Flink TaskManager (IPC)
6123:
  comment: Apache Flink JobManager
6130:
  comment: Apache Flink JobManager (BLOB Server)
8081:
  comment: Apache Flink JobManager (Web UI)
```

The same ports described in `flink-conf.yaml`:

```
jobmanager.rpc.address: app-1.stag.local
jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
jobmanager.heap.mb: 1024

taskmanager.heap.mb: 2048
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 4
taskmanager.memory.preallocate: false

blob.server.port: 6130

parallelism.default: 4

jobmanager.web.port: 8081

state.backend: jobmanager

restart-strategy: none
restart-strategy.fixed-delay.attempts: 2
restart-strategy.fixed-delay.delay: 60s
```

So, I have two questions:

1. This exception related to blocked ports. Right?
2. Which ports should I open on firewall for standalone Apache Flink cluster?

**UPDATE 1**

I found configuration problem in `masters` and `slaves` files (I skip new line separators between hosts described in these files). I fixed it and now I see other exceptions:

- [flink--taskmanager-0-app-1.stag.local.log](https://gist.github.com/maxd/9859eb8c4bcfb62b53b0)
- [flink--taskmanager-0-app-2.stag.local.log](https://gist.github.com/maxd/cd5073b8b635d2ab149e)

I have 2 nodes:

- app-1.stag.local (with running job and task managers)
- app-2.stag.local (with running task manager)

As you can see from these logs the app-1.stag.local task manager can't connect to other task manager:

> java.io.IOException: Connecting the channel failed: Connecting to remote task manager + 'app-2.stag.local/192.168.38.98:35806' has failed. This might indicate that the remote task manager has been lost.

but app-2.stag.local has open port:

> 2016-03-18 16:24:14,347 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.NettyServer         - Successful initialization (took 39 ms). Listening on SocketAddress /192.168.38.98:35806

So, I think problem related to firewall but I don't understand where I can configure this port (or range of ports) in Apache Flink.

Comment: I'm not so sure that this is a firewall configuration problem since the `JobManager` and the `TaskManager` already communicated with each other. Could you share the taskmanager.log file to of the TaskManager `192.168.18.98:46369`?

Comment: I found configuration problem in `master` and `slaves` files. I fixed it and now I see other exceptions (I am going to update question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a problem: `taskmanager.data.port` parameter was set to 0 by default (but [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/setup/config.html) say what it should be set to `6121`).

So, I set this port in `flink-conf.yaml` and now all works fine.

Comment: I didn't find in the docs that you linked something saying that we should set it to `6121`. How much sure this was the solution?